# How do I create a tooltip with overflow visible in Google Maps V3?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create a tooltip that overflows outside the map if necessary but I can't figure it out.
I have implemented the tooltip with help from this [guy](https://github.com/medelbou/Tooltip-for-Google-Maps) and it works like a charm except that when the tooltip is to large it doesn't overflow outside of the map box.

[image: fail1]
[image: fail2]

In my create marker method where I create and populate my markers with data i create the tooltip.

**createMarker**

```
function createMarker(number, currentMap, currentMapData) {
                var marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
                    position:new google.maps.LatLng(currentMapData[0], currentMapData[1]),
                    map:currentMap,
                    icon:'/img/sticker/empty.png',
                    shadow:'/img/sticker/bubble_shadow.png',
                    transparent:'/img/sticker/bubble_transparent.png',
                    draggable:false,
                    raiseOnDrag:false,
                    labelContent:"" + number,
                    labelAnchor:new google.maps.Point(3, 30),
                    labelClass:"mapIconLabel", // the CSS class for the label
                    labelInBackground:false
                });

                var html = mapHtml(currentMapData[7], currentMapData[2], currentMapData[4], currentMapData[13], currentMapData[11], currentMapData[12], currentMapData[3], currentMapData[5])

                var tooltipOptions = {marker:marker, content:html, cssClass:'tooltip', href:"/"+currentMapData[7]};
                // create the tooltip
                var tooltip = new Tooltip(tooltipOptions);
            }
```

**tooltip.js**

```
function Tooltip(options) {

    // Now initialize all properties.
    this.marker_ = options.marker;
    this.content_ = options.content;
    this.map_ = options.marker.get('map');
    this.cssClass_ = options.cssClass||null;

    // We define a property to hold the content's
    // div. We'll actually create this div
    // upon receipt of the add() method so we'll
    // leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    //Explicitly call setMap on this overlay
    this.setMap(this.map_);
    var me = this;
    // Show tooltip on mouseover event.
    google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, 'mouseover', function() {
        me.show();
    });
    // Hide tooltip on mouseout event.
    google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, 'mouseout', function() {
        me.hide();
    });

    // When clicked move to href
    google.maps.event.addListener(me.marker_, 'click', function() {
        window.location.href = options.href;
    });

}
// Now we extend google.maps.OverlayView()
Tooltip.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// onAdd is one of the functions that we must implement,
// it will be called when the map is ready for the overlay to be attached.
Tooltip.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    // Create the DIV and set some basic attributes.
    var div = document.createElement('DIV');
    div.style.position = "absolute";
    // Hide tooltip
    div.style.visibility = "hidden";
    if(this.cssClass_)
        div.className += " "+this.cssClass_;

    //Attach content to the DIV.
    div.innerHTML = this.content_;

    // Set the overlay's div_ property to this DIV
    this.div_ = div;

    // We add an overlay to a map via one of the map's panes.
    // We'll add this overlay to the floatPane pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.floatPane.appendChild(this.div_);

}
// We here implement draw
Tooltip.prototype.draw = function() {

    // Position the overlay. We use the position of the marker
    // to peg it to the correct position, just northeast of the marker.
    // We need to retrieve the projection from this overlay to do this.
    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();

    // Retrieve the coordinates of the marker
    // in latlngs and convert them to pixels coordinates.
    // We'll use these coordinates to place the DIV.
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.marker_.getPosition());

    // Position the DIV.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = ne.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';

}
// We here implement onRemove
Tooltip.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
}

// Note that the visibility property must be a string enclosed in quotes
Tooltip.prototype.hide = function() {
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}

Tooltip.prototype.show = function() {
    if (this.div_) {
        this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```

I have tried to set `this.div_.style.overflow = "visible";` in code and with css but It doesn't work. Do you have any idea what I should do?
**To sum it up: How do I make my tooltop overflow outside the map?**

Comment: It's not an issue of the tooltip's overflow, it's an issue of the map's overflow. Nothing inside the DOM of the map-container may go outside of the map.  To achieve the desired result you must create an element outside the map-container and update it's position inside the page when the viewport of the map changes.

Comment: Aha! That makes sense! Thank you! Do you have any pointers? Maybe a tutorial somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using @Dr.Molle's suggestion here's a basic template for overflowing tooltips on google maps. It should give you a start on however you want to extend it in your own implementation. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/VzYF6/) demo that you can use to follow along.

First thing I did was create a `div` to hold the info I want in my tooltip. Next, apply some initial styling to this container:

```
#marker-tooltip {
  display: none;
  position:absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

Keep in mind, the tooltip `div` should be included inside the same parent container as your map's `div` (for the positioning to work properly).

Next we want to store the information we include inside the tooltip somewhere, I did this by creating an attribute to the `marker` object called `tooltipContent`:

```
marker.tooltipContent = 'this content should go inside the tooltip';
```

Then, you want to be able to set the content to the tooltip `div` and show it when the user mouseover's on the `marker` - and you can do this using the map api's event listener for `mouseover` on the `marker` and using `jQuery`'s `$.html()` and `$.show()` functions:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {        
    $('#marker-tooltip').html(marker.tooltipContent).show();
});
```

Now, you have the tooltip with it's contents showing on `mouseover` of the `marker` - however it's not positioned properly. This is the tricky part. You need to find the pixel coordinates of the map's `div` that the `marker`'s `latlng` is currently on. Luckily, the maps api has functions to obtain these values - and for simplicity I borrowed the solution posted [here](http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/google-maps-api-v3-convert-latlng-object-to-actual-pixels-point-object). If you're interested in further readings behind this, I suggest starting with the section on [Map Coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapCoordinates) in the doc.

Anyways, once you've made a reference to the function provided in that solution - you can obtain the pixel values of the marker:

```
var point = fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition(), map);
```

Where `point.x` will equal the horizontal pixel value on the map's `div` and `point.y` will equal the vertical pixel value on the map's `div`. Once you have these values, you can change the tooltip's absolute position accordingly using `$.css()` method. So the listener will be updated to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
    var point = fromLatLngToPoint(marker.getPosition(), map);
    $('#marker-tooltip').html(marker.tooltipContent).css({ 'left': point.x, 'top': point.y }).show();
});
```

And of course, you should add a listener for the `mouseout` event on the marker to hide the tooltip:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function () {
    $('#marker-tooltip').hide();
});
```

Comment: This is perfect! Worked like charm. Removed Tooltip all along and modified your code a bit with: 1. // When clicked move to href
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    window.location.href = '\/'+ currentMapData[7];
                });                                                     so that instead of opening a infowindow popup i move to the correct location on click                                                    2. 'left': point.x - 250, to place the popup window to the left since my map is on the right =). Thank you!